# Tokens in field widget don't work

Tags: 8, tokens

I am using drupal 8. I want to add tokens to the paragraph image field widget as data-attribute, but it doesn't work. What can be caused by this problem? Is it need some modules? Here screenshot:

[image: field data attribute with token]

[image: used token for image field]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the wrong token field for the paragraph image field. Instead of [media...] token need to use [paragraph:...] token, as the field is paragraph field.